# How do I populate dropdownlist inside Razor pages Not MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

How do I populate dropdownlist inside Razor pages Not MVC because
I have the code working fine in .Net core MVC but not working in .Net core Razor Page
How do I display the list in dropdown with **asp-items="????????"** i mean

How do I display from here

```
public IActionResult Droplist()
   {
        List<ListMode> _Define = PopulateList();
        return View(new SelectList(_Define, "PredefineID", "Predefine"));
    }
```

**return View(……);** in above code is not working in Razor page

In side my Razor page I have this.

```
@Page
@model…
<form method="post">
<select id="ddlDList" name="PredefineID" asp-items="????????">
<option value="0">Please select</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Other part of the code
Database: **dbo.DropListTBL**

| PredefineID | Predefine |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Class |
| 2 | Subject |
| 3 | Option |
| 4 | Status |

Model Class:

```
public class ListMode
{
    public int PredefineID { get; set; }
    public string Predefine { get; set; }
}
```

Also:

```
private static List<ListMode> PopulateList()
    {
        string constr = @"Data Source =.; initial Catalog = DBname; Integrated Security = True";
        List<ListMode> List_Mode = new List<ListMode>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "SELECT PredefineID, Predefine FROM dbo.DropListTBL";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        List_Mode.Add(new ListMode
                        {
                            Predefine = sdr["Predefine"].ToString(),
                            PredefineID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["PredefineID"])
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        return List_Mode;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo about populating dropdownlist inside Razor pages:

cshtml.cs:

```
    [BindProperty]
            public SelectList ListModes { get; set; }
            public IActionResult OnGet()
            {
                List<ListMode> _Define =PopulateList();
                ListModes = new SelectList(_Define, "PredefineID", "Predefine");
                return Page();
            }
```

cshtml:

```
<select id="ddlDList" name="PredefineID" asp-items="@Model.ListModes">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I just tried this out, with a little adjustment on my code its work fine, thank you for that.